# How to change font in separate runs

Tags: python, python-docx

I tried to change formatting in single run, without using styles according documentation https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

I don't know why but below example doesn't change it.

```
import os, sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Menu
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def create_offer():
    offer = Document()
    p = offer.add_paragraph("Just a paragraph")
    run = offer.add_paragraph("Test run").add_run()
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'Calibri'
    font.bold = True
    font.size = Pt(12)
    run = offer.add_paragraph("2nd test run").add_run()
    offer.save("Demo.docx")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add your import statements to the question?

Comment: make sure you have `from docx import Document` and `from docx.shared import Pt` in your imports

Answer (score 1):

You should add the text that you want to format as a parameter in `add_run()` function, instead of `add_paragraph()` function.

Your `create_offer` function will then look like

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def create_offer():
    offer = Document()
    p = offer.add_paragraph("Just a paragraph")
    run = offer.add_paragraph().add_run("Test run")
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'Calibri'
    font.bold = True
    font.size = Pt(12)
    run = offer.add_paragraph().add_run("2nd test run")
    offer.save("Demo.docx")
```